# Chance for three 100 rolls out of seven tries

Tags: probability

So you have seven tries to do something that has a 1% chance success rate, you manage to do it three times out of those seven. What is the probability of this?

I've tried to go forward myself, but I am unsure if its correct or false.

What I did:

$$P(X=3) = {{7}\choose{3}} \times\left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^3 \times \left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^4 = 0.00000224139...$$

Comment: Why $7/3$ in your calculation?

Comment: By $7/3$ you mean ${7 \choose 3}$?

Comment: Yes John, I didnt know how to do that in the calculator

Comment: You need to check [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) out before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use the binomial distribution

for the  binomial distribution

$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

$$P(X=3)=\binom{7}{3} (1/100)^3 (99/100)^{4}=3.36208604*10^{-5}=0.000033620860$$ 
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
$$\binom{7}{3}=\frac{7!}{3!(7-3)!}=\frac{7*6*5*4!}{3!*4!}=\frac{7*6*5}{3*2*1}=35$$

Comment: Thank you! Was very helpful with the letters to see what is what!

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

The correct value for the first factor is ${7 \choose 3} = \frac{7!}{3!4!} = 35$ rather than $7/3$. The numeric value was calculated with $7/3$ so that's incorrect.